# Wordpress Users and pages manager

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, authentication, dataviewmanager

Kindly give me some help on this issue and suggest a solution with plug in or something could help
Issue:
I am building a normal website that all can see it, but I need for some pages to be hidden for registered user only, and registered users have a categories every one of them (or group) can use group of pages and posts.
I need a plugin that manage registration and admin confirmation and allow admin to classify a group of pages for every registered user.
 Thanks I will appreciate your help.
Mona Amin

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin,

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-manager/

This would help you for your requirement. Let me know if you need any other help.